# Autorun Bash Script after Login to Sync Git Repos

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have already a [gitupdate.sh](http://sweetme.at/2013/10/08/keep-a-local-git-repository-synchronized-with-a-remote-git-repository/) that I found on the internet.

My problem now is how to make the script run automatically every time I log into my Ubuntu 14.04 computer.

I have tried adding this line to `.bashrc`

sh '/path/to/git/repo/gitupdate.sh'

The problem here is the script is executed not in the context or path of the repo thus **the script runs in a folder that is not initialized with git.** (I don't actually know what folder bashrc run on)

What want to do is that **the update script to be run by Ubuntu in the context of the path so the script will not fail.** And also show the running script in a Terminal window that will not automatically close.

And the ultimate goal, is to be able automatically upon login, that git cloned repos to be synced with the public repos.

Comment: It looks like you need to provide the repo to update as an argument to the script: `gitupdate.sh /path/to/repo`.

Comment: I'd also take a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/98433/run-a-script-on-login-using-bash-login.  You want to make sure you're not running it every time you spawn a new shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(cd repo && bash /path/to/gitupdate.sh)
```

Comment: May worth sending it to the background to not wait while it finishes

Comment: It depends on the output produced by the script and how many of these commands you have the intention of running, or the output may be confusing

Comment: this is the output bash: cd: repo: No such file or directory

Comment: well... I meant the "real" name of your repo

Comment: @dtmilano yes I put the real path there. and that is the output

Answer (score 0):

Just open the **gitupdate.sh** and at the beginning of the file just add the command to go to the selected direcotry. For example:

> cd /var/test